# How do I identify the users on Oracle database who uses OS authentication?

Tags: linux, windows, oracle

I'm trying to audit the privileged users on Oracle Db and see there are users for whom the last login column appears to be blank, however, I'm aware that those user accounts are used for certain processes. Hence wanted to understand if there is a way to identify users on the Oracle database who uses OS authentication? and what is the table I should be looking at?

I See the "Authentication Type" for all the users in the DBA_Users table specify "PASSWORD"

Comment: Are there any users whose name has prefix `OPS$` (in DBA_USERS)? For example, `OPS$SCOTT`? They might be the ones you're looking for.

Comment: _"however, I'm aware that those user accounts are used for certain processes. "_   stored procedures can be launched with dbms_scheduler, so no logon needed, so no update of 'last_logon'.

Answer (score 3):

For currently logged in users:

Check the `AUTHENTICATION_TYPE` column of [V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/V-SESSION_CONNECT_INFO.html#GUID-9F0DCAEA-A67E-4183-89E7-B1555DC591CE).

> AUTHENTICATION_TYPE
>
> VARCHAR2(26)
>
> How the user was authenticated:
>
> DATABASE - Username/password authentication
>
> OS - Operating system external user authentication
>
> NETWORK - Network protocol or ANO authentication
>
> PROXY - OCI proxy connection authentication
>
> SERVER
>
> PASSWORD
>
> EXTERNAL ADAPTERS
>
> INTERNAL
>
> GLOBAL
>
> EXTERNAL
>
> PASSWORD BASED GLOBAL USER

In general, you can check `AUTHENTICATION_TYPE` column of [DBA_USERS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/DBA_USERS.html#GUID-309FCCB2-2E8D-4371-9FC5-7F3B10E2A8C0):

> AUTHENTICATION_TYPE
>
> VARCHAR2(8)
>
> Indicates the authentication mechanism for the user:
>
> NONE - The user has not been configured for an authentication method
>
> EXTERNAL - CREATE USER user1 IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;
>
> GLOBAL - CREATE USER user2 IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY;
>
> PASSWORD - CREATE USER user3 IDENTIFIED BY user3;

OS authentication users are defined as `EXTERNAL`. The prefix can be changed with the parameter `os_authent_prefix`, but the default value is `ops$`.